# Align table header and body on the mod tools page

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, design, 10k-tools

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days

> [image]

1st column in the header has class `col-1`:

```
.col-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
}
```

But 1st column in the body has class `col-2`:

```
.col-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}
```

So, you just need to use the same class.

Also, it's kinda strange to use div's instead of table for such thing.